# Give jQuery plugin access to selected DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, plugins

I'm experimenting with writing a plugin for jQuery that doesn't follow the pattern outlined int his document: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

It is as follows:

```
(function( $ ){

$.fn.insert = {
    'hello': function(text){ 
        $(this).text(text); 
    },
    'goodbye': function(){
        alert('goodbye');
    }
}
})( jQuery );
```

The page instantiates this plugin with this code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#test').insert.goodbye();
    $('#test').insert.hello('blahblahblah');
});
```

In this form, `.goodbye()` does initializes correct, but as is probably obvious, `.hello()` does not. On inspecting the `this` in firebug, it shows the scope to belong to its containing function. (cue facepalm).

How do I give the function inside 'hello' access to the selected DOM objects? I'm not really interested in having a discussion as to why or why not one should create a plugin in this fashion. It's more an academic exercise for me.

P.S. I should also note that I get this error when the `hello()` portion attempts to run: `doc.createDocumentFragment is not a function`.

**UPDATE**

```
(function( $ ){

$.fn.insert = {
    'el': this,
    'hello': function(text){ 
        $(this.el).text(text); 
    },
    'goodbye': function(){
        alert('goodbye');
    }
}

})( jQuery );
```

Made this update to the code. FYI, Firebug *does* show that `this.el` references the DOM object in question, and `text` is still carrying the passed string, but it's still not inserting the text into the element, and still giving me the aforementioned error.

Comment: when I run this, this.el references the global object (window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure... but this works:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            (function($){

                $.fn.myinsert = function(){

                    this.hello = function(text){ 
                        $(this).text(text);
                    };

                    this.goodbye = function(){
                        alert('goodbye');
                    };

                    return this; //this is the gotcha

                };

            })(jQuery);

            $(function(){
                var test = $('#test');
                test.myinsert().goodbye(); 
                test.myinsert().hello('heyo');
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="test">My name is</div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `test.myinsert.goodbye();` itself does indeed fire, so I know that you can call a method from within the object. I've even been able to achieve a rudimentary way to get the referenced element in there with an additional property: `'el': this,`, however, I'm still having trouble getting the `hello` method to fire.

Comment: Thanks much! Works perfectly. Incidentally, I've discovered that by returning `this` in each of those methods, you can also chain from the plugin! Isn't that wonderful!?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined "insert" as an object sitting on the jQuery object, instead of a function that can be called on a selection. I don't think you can ever get the scope of the current selection with it structured that way. You can call goodbye() successfully since it doesn't rely on any context/scope to execute.